# How to use UIImagePickerController along with UITabBar in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using TabBarController in my application. In one of the view of the tabbar I am using a `UIImagePickerController` to pick an image.

When I add the picker as follows

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.delegate = self;

imagePicker.editing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
```

It adds the picker, But at the time of choosing the photo, The bottom bar having the buttons "choose" and "cancel" gets hide under my tabbar. How to resolve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this problem - I have an app that uses a `UITabBar` and a `UIImagePickerController` together, and the tab bar does not obscure the image picker.

Inside my view controller, which is one of the `UITabBar`'s view controllers, I'm creating the image picker as such:

```
self.imagePicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Seems very similar to your code, except that I'm setting the image picker as a retained property.  Is your tab bar set up correctly?  Is the view controller contained within the `myTabBar.viewControllers` array?

Comment: Yes It is. I have a tabbar whose first controller is say firstViewCtonroller which has a navigationController. Using this navigationController I switch to different views and in one of the view I am using the above code. But the tabBar is not getting hidden under the imagePicker`s view.

Comment: Hey are you also facing any memory leak when you use the UIImageController.

Comment: Hey You might not be allowing the user to edit the Image. When You allow, the next view comes along with the tabBar at the bottom.

Comment: Good point, I'm not doing that.  I will try it out and see if the tab bar shows up.

Comment: Why is this answer accepted? There is no solution for the problem in it. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using self as the navigation controller that shows the modal screen. Therefore the tab bar navigation controller does not know that a modal screen should fill the whole screen. Since the UIImagePickerController can not adjust itself to a smaller size you have to use the tab bar navigation controller to open present the modal view.

I use the following code to show a UIImagePickerController from a navigation controller that is shown inside a tabbar:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

using self.navigationController instead of self as the object that presents the UIImagePickerController did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
picker.delegate = currentClassViewController;

[tabBarController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Have your picker-caller class own or have access to your `UITabController` variable and `presentModalViewController` against your `tabBarController`.